# Properties of groups with integer exponents

Tags: group-theory, exponential-function, binary-operations, inverse-semigroups

For any elements a and b from a group $\lt A,\ * \gt$ and any integer n, prove that

$\begin{align}
& (a^{-1}\cdot b\cdot a)^n = a^{-1}\cdot b^n\cdot a
\end{align}$

This is what I tried:

LHS:

$\begin{align}
& \quad \ \ \ a^{-n}\cdot b^n\cdot a^n=(a^{-n}\cdot a^n) \cdot b^n=(a^{-1}\cdot a)^n\cdot b^n \\
&= \ e^n\cdot b^n\qquad \text{where $e$ is the identity element of the group }
\end{align}$

And this is where I get stuck. I know that the identity elements are usually 1 and 0 and the power n should disappear but I don't know how to show that logically.

Please show me a better way to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Note: $a^{-n}*b^n * a^n = (a^{-n}*a^n)b^n$ is true **only** when  $*$ is commutative on $A$.  You need to prove the statement as holding for *all* groups.

Comment: To see the light, try first with $n=2$:
$$(a^{-1}ba)^2=(a^{-1}ba)(a^{-1}ba)=a^{-1}baa^{-1}ba=a^{-1}beba=a^{-1}b^2a.$$

Answer (score 2):

Try induction on $n$.

Beware, groups may be non-commutative. In general $(a^{-1}ba)^n$
is not equal to $a^{-n}b^na^n$.

Comment: I've already upvoted this, but I'll add that ultimately, for a solid proof, one does indeed need induction to prove the statement.  I think one of the other posts does a great job at revealing intuitively what is going on, proceeding with induction on $n$ can do the same.

Answer (score 2):

Writing out the product in full
$$
(a^{-1} b a )^{n}
=
\underbrace{(a^{-1} b a ) (a^{-1} b a ) \ldots (a^{-1} b a )}_{\large n\text{ factors of } a^{-1}ba}
$$

Groups are associative so we can rewrite
$$
a^{-1} b (a  a^{-1}) b  \ldots b ( a a^{-1}) b a 
$$

$a a^{-1} = e$ so we get
$$
a^{-1} b e b  \ldots b e b a 
$$

$be = b$ so we can replace each of these with $b$ in the above
$$
a^{-1} b  b  \ldots b  b a 
$$
where there are $n$ $b$'s

which gives finally
$$
a^{-1} b^{n} a 
$$

Comment: Paul Aljabar: I hope you don't mind my edit.  If you wish I hadn't edited the post, click othe the blue phrase "edited x mins ago" (sits above the most recent editor's icon)  and you can roll back to your original version.)  Or let me know, and I will do that for you.

Comment: Not at all, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$(a^{-1} b a)^n = (a^{-1}ba) \dots (a^{-1} b a) = a^{-1} (b a a^{-1})(b a a^{-1}) \dots(b a a^{-1}) a $

This is just

$a^{-1}(b e)( be ) \dots (be) a = a^{-1} (b \dots b) a = a^{-1} b^n a $

Comment: Don't rely too much on $\ldots$.  Suppose $n$ is 6.  In your last equation, for all we know you could be claiming $a^{-1}(bbbb)a = a^{-1}b^4a$ and would prove nothing, because $4\neq 6$.  So you can improve your answer by explaining a bit?

Comment: The OP is more than welcome to fill the steps in if they don't follow something.

Comment: That's fine...just that the "filling the dots" is the most difficult part of the solution.  Of course, you're free to do the easy part, and hand-wave the rest.

Comment: The filling in the dots is actually the easiest portion.  The point of this exercise is to trip students up with commutativity and showing them that they can rearrange the order of multiplication to cancel out the internal factors.  There's nothing handwavey going on.

Comment: One does not "need" induction here.

Comment: @amWhy This is one of those occasions, where an honest induction can IMHO be replaced with an ellipsis. Of course, this depends **very much** on the level students. If they have seen this type of an induction enough many times, they can manage. If presenting this on a chalkboard I don't think I would bother doing a full induction. I might give it as a homework assignment. Just to make sure :-) I quite understand if your experience in teaching tells you to go with a full induction in class. Not sure that it is necessary here. But, this is likely a dupe anyway.

Comment: And, if you keep one-upping each other, I will apply a blunt instrument. So far I think I can get away with judicious editing of comments. Cool it. Both of you.